# PayPal and Rails Dilemma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment, activemerchant, merchant-account

So I'd like to integrate paypal into my rails app using active merchant. In this app, users are signing up for courses that other users are teaching and users need to be able to pay each other in order to take the course.

My problem is that I need to take a percentage of each transaction that occurs.

So should I have all of the transactions paid to my merchant account and then pay each user individually? That seems crazy unless there's a way to automate it. Is there maybe a way that I can transfer user payments between each other but take a percentage out as the intermediary? If so how could I do that?

Really stuck here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was also wondering about this exact issue -- specifically if this process can be done w/o a paypal Website Payments Pro account. The reason I'm skeptical that this is possible through W.P. Standard is because Paypal processes all transactions with the latter, as opposed to you (the merchant site). It seems ridiculous that this is such a poorly documented issue...

Comment: Zach: I just found out the name for this type of service is chained payments. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478427/paypal-adaptivechained-payment-with-rails 

and https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments

[Adaptive payments is a term paypal uses for chained payments]

Comment: Me too, after much research I found that the paypal_adaptive gem is set up to handle chained payments. Although it does take some amount of hacking. And yes this is so poorly documented.

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to my comments:

Check out the SDK listed in the link I gave with the comments. They have a sample RoR app laid out which should tell you pretty much exactly how to do each kind of adaptive payment with Rails. Just beware that there are **many** errors in this application. Look at James' answer on this question to fix them:

[How can I avoid auth and time issues using Paypal's Adaptive Payments API with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717735/is-anyone-using-paypals-adaptive-payments-api-with-ruby)

Also, thanks for the heads up on the paypal_adaptive gem.

EDIT: Here's the SDK link just in case. https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk